# What can be defined outside any class in C#?

Tags: c#

I heard that

- in Java, everything is defined in classes, except classes themselves.
- C# and Java are very similar languages.

So i thought that it is the same case for C#, until I saw two examples, where a enum type and a delegate type are not defined within any class:

```
using System; 
enum Color 
{ 
  Red, 
   Green, 
   Blue 
} 
class Test 
{ 
  static void PrintColor(Color color) { 
    switch (color) { 
      case Color.Red: 
        Console.WriteLine("Red"); 
        break; 
      case Color.Green: 
        Console.WriteLine("Green"); 
        break; 
      case Color.Blue: 
        Console.WriteLine("Blue"); 
        break; 
      default: 
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown color"); 
        break; 
    } 
  } 
  static void Main() { 
    Color c = Color.Red; 
    PrintColor(c); 
    PrintColor(Color.Blue); 
  } 
}
```

and

```
using System; 
delegate double Function(double x); 
class Multiplier 
{ 
  double factor; 
  public Multiplier(double factor) { 
    this.factor = factor; 
  } 
  public double Multiply(double x) { 
    return x * factor; 
  } 
} 
class Test 
{ 
  static double Square(double x) { 
    return x * x; 
  } 
  static double[] Apply(double[] a, Function f) { 
    double[] result = new double[a.Length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) result[i] = f(a[i]); 
    return result; 
  } 
  static void Main() { 
    double[] a = {0.0, 0.5, 1.0}; 
    double[] squares = Apply(a, Square); 
    double[] sines = Apply(a, Math.Sin); 
    Multiplier m = new Multiplier(2.0); 
    double[] doubles =  Apply(a, m.Multiply); 
  } 
}
```

So what can be defined outside any class in C#?

Based on the above examples, can the definition of  any type be defined outside any class?

Thanks.

Comment: In java everything is Object.

Comment: A class is a type.  Types can be defined globally in a namespace or within a class (nested) in a namespace.  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here...

Comment: An `enum` and a `delegate` is a type, and any type can be defined at global scope.

Comment: @Omore Everything in C# is an object...

Comment: @john Except pointers.

Comment: And type definitions aren't objects - although they *have* a type, and a type is an object...

Comment: Surely they aren't objects in java either? How would that... nevermind.

Comment: @john Java doesn't have pointers, and so doesn't have that exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465307/definition-of-enums-outside-the-class-body-but-inside-namespace

Comment: Java does not have delegates but it does have Enum types and they can be created outside class.

Comment: Structs, interfaces, `using` directives?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Java and C# enums are a whole world apart. Java enums can be defined outside classes because they are themselves fully fledged classes. Just like any class, Java enums can contain methods, constructors, fields, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C# specification, in **B2.6 Namespaces**,

> - compilation-unit:
>     extern-alias-directives<sub>opt</sub>   using-directives<sub>opt</sub>  global-attributes<sub>opt</sub>
>         namespace-member-declarations<sub>opt</sub>
> - namespace-declaration:
>     namespace   qualified-identifier   namespace-body   ;<sub>opt</sub>
> - qualified-identifier:
>     identifier
>     qualified-identifier   .   identifier
> - namespace-body:
>     {   extern-alias-directives<sub>opt</sub>   using-directives<sub>opt</sub>   namespace-member-declarations<sub>opt</sub>   }
> - extern-alias-directives:
>     extern-alias-directive
>     extern-alias-directives   extern-alias-directive
> - extern-alias-directive:
>     extern   alias   identifier   ;
> - using-directives:
>     using-directive
>     using-directives   using-directive
> - using-directive:
>     using-alias-directive
>     using-namespace-directive
> - using-alias-directive:
>     using   identifier   =   namespace-or-type-name   ;
> - using-namespace-directive:
>     using   namespace-name   ;
> - namespace-member-declarations:
>     namespace-member-declaration
>     namespace-member-declarations   namespace-member-declaration
> - namespace-member-declaration:
>     namespace-declaration
>     type-declaration
> - type-declaration:
>     class-declaration
>     struct-declaration
>     interface-declaration
>     enum-declaration
>     delegate-declaration
> - qualified-alias-member:
>     identifier   ::   identifier   type-argument-list<sub>opt</sub>

According to rule **namespace-member-declaration**, those can be placed outside any class in C# is

> namespace-declaration
>     type-declaration

Namely, **namespace** and **type**.

And type contains:

> type-declaration:
>     class-declaration
>     struct-declaration
>     interface-declaration
>     enum-declaration
>     delegate-declaration

So the answer is **namespace**, **class**, **struct**, **interface**, **enum**, **delegate** declaration. Note I don't regard directives, like *using-alias-directive*, as definitions here.

*You can find the spec file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC#\Specifications\1033` if you are using VS2017.*